# Brace initialization of structs

Tags: c++11, list-initialization

In the following code

```
struct BinaryNode {
  int val;
  BinaryNode *leftchild, *rightchild;
};

struct NaryNode {
  int val;
  std::vector<NaryNode*> children;
};
```

I can initialize the first struct as

```
  std::unique_ptr<BinaryNode> bnode1(new BinaryNode{4});
```

but the second one fails

```
  std::unique_ptr<NaryNode> nnode1(new NaryNode{4});
```

What gives ?

EDIT: The compiler error is

```
tree.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tree.cpp:41:68: error: no matching function for call to ‘NaryNode::NaryNode(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
tree.cpp:41:68: note: candidates are:
tree.cpp:10:8: note: NaryNode::NaryNode()
tree.cpp:10:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
tree.cpp:10:8: note: NaryNode::NaryNode(const NaryNode&)
tree.cpp:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
tree.cpp:10:8: note: NaryNode::NaryNode(NaryNode&&)
tree.cpp:10:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Version:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

Build command:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x tree.cpp
```

Comment: Post the compiler error (seems ok http://ideone.com/LewfQE).

Comment: I see ... so this might just be specific to this version of g++. Thanks for posting the ideone link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From section *8.5.1 Aggregates* of the c++11 standard (draft n3337):

> 1 An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equal initializers for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).
>
> 2 When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list
> are taken as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript or member order...

And from section *8.5.4 List-initialization*:

> List-initialization can be used
>
> - as the initializer in a variable definition (8.5)
> - **as the initializer in a new expression (5.3.4)**

This means `NaryNode` is an aggregate and can be list initialized (using `{}`).
The compiler is incorrect to reject the `NaryNode` snippet, g++ v4.7.2 compiles it fine (see http://ideone.com/LewfQE).